# Magento 1 issue with adding New Product image?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

In magento 1.9.2.0,face an issue with image upload for new product in admin side.browse button working and upload button is working but image is not showing.Please observe link [image](http://prntscr.com/l3ffq2)

Comment: it might cause browser flash player issue also, tried install flash player or change browser to just double check

Comment: Installed the browser flash player agian the same issue http://prntscr.com/l3fl4e .Image uploaded but its not showing

Comment: Check your console tab when you save the image. Is there any error?

Comment: its not showing any error in console tab

Comment: @DineshYadav this issue only with new products.for old products image uploaded and its showing

Comment: What is the browser you are using? Can you test it in google chrome?

Comment: i am using chrome.i tested in chrome and firefox also

Answer (score 0):

There might be problem of below one,

1. Check flash player is properly installed or not, Might be create issue regarding to flash player.
2. Did you check given media folder with root permission or not.
3. Check at  lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php file around line 541,

   if (!(@is_dir($destinationFolder) || @mkdir($destinationFolder, 0777, true)))

If Issue Solved please let reply

Comment: followed this  steps but agian same issue  http://prntscr.com/l3fl4e

Answer (score 0):

Did you applied any patch recently? 
This issues came usually after patch installation . Anyway from my suggestion check this options:

1. Open the lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php and check the file permissions , in this link [Pemissions fix](https://my.aspirationhosting.com/knowledgebase/1482/Image-Upload-Issue-with-Magento-1923-or-SUPEE-7405.html) theres a fix for that .
2. Add this patch https://github.com/adampmoss/CreareSEO/pull/78/files .

Comment: Followed the above steps.but issue is not resolved.
Changed line @mkdir($destinationFolder, 0750, true) to @mkdir($destinationFolder, 0755, true)